# How to redirect react website into other website with image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to create some website using react-bootstrap and I wanted to redirect my user to another website/link when they click on some logo on my footer, How can I do that in react ? because I realize that  tag will only redirect the path of our website.

Here's my code:

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
import '../CSS/Footer.css'

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <Container fluid={true} className="p-0 footerContainer">
                        <Row>
                <Col sm={12} lg={4} className="text-center footerright">
                    <h3>Follow Us</h3>
                    <hr style={{border:'2px solid', color:'#FFFFFF', width:'25.7%', margin: 'auto'}}></hr>
                    <img src="FBLogo.jpg"></img>
                    <img src="IGLogo.jpg"></img>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <Row>
                <Col sm={12} lg={12} className="text-center">
                    <hr></hr>
                    <p>Copyright © 2014 <br></br>All Rights Reserved</p>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

Answer (score 2):

### **Just like in normal HTML, You will wrap an image with a link tag:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="FBLogo.jpg"/></a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="IGLogo.jpg"/></a>
```

**Or using a `workmap`:**

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="400" height="379">

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="stack_overflow" href="https://www.google.com/">
</map>
```